# xhookrightarrow and xmapsto?

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I use `$\xrightarrow{f}$` a lot and I found myself in need of the corresponding commands `\xmapsto` and `\xhookrightarrow` quite a few times and I was wondering if there is anything like it. I'd like to produce

(i) a labeled hookrightarrow

(ii) a labeled mapsto

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A tip: you can highlight commands and small portions of code by enclosing it between two backticks `` Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not sure, whether you mean those commands with labels, but I think they could provide the relevant symbols:

`\xmapsto{label}`, `\xhookrightarrow`, all from `mathtools` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
\xmapsto{\text{Look here}} &&  x\\
\xrightarrow{\text{Something}} && y \\
\xhookrightarrow{\text{Something completely different}} && z 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please have also a look on `http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf`, which provides a (perhaps not complete, but near to it) overview of symbols in `LaTeX`

Comment: Ooh! mathtools was exactly what I needed! : ) Thank you very much for this helpful answer. It does make one wonder though why `xrightarrow`does not need the same package included as the other two commands.

Comment: @MattN. `\xrightarrow` is a command already available by ususal `amsmath` and perhaps redefined/improved in `mathtools` (I did not check for it now), but not `\xmapsto` and `\xhookrightarrow` (as far as I know). To make it work. If you include both `amsmath` and `mathtools`, `amsmath` **must** come before the other one.

Comment: `mathtools` does not touch `\xrightarrow`, we only provide the extra ones.

Comment: @daleif: Ok, I already guessed that, therefore I wrote *perhaps*. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 5):

A minimal implementation if you do not wish to import `mathtools`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\xmapstofill@}{%
  \arrowfill@{\mapstochar\relbar}\relbar\rightarrow
}
\providecommand*{\xmapsto}[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0395\xmapstofill@{#1}{#2}%
}

\providecommand*{\xhookrightfill@}{%
  \arrowfill@{\lhook\joinrel\relbar}\relbar\rightarrow
}
\providecommand*{\xhookrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0395\xhookrightfill@{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \xmapsto[under]{over} B \]
and
\[ A \xhookrightarrow[under]{over} B \]
\end{document}
```

AMSmath's `\ext@arrow` is the command that generates the extensible arrow composed of the chars defined in its fifth argument, in this case `\xmapstofill@`; in turn this defines the arrow to start with `\mapstochar\relbar` (`|-`) then repeat `\relbar` (`-`) as many times as needed to fit the label, then end with `\rightarrow` (`->`).

Comment: What about the same for `\hookrightarrow`?

Comment: @Sigur there you go!